# ACF Post object Is not pulling the Correct Featured image

Tags: post, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF post object field to display related recipes on posts.

I have used below code to make it happen, its pulling correct posts and title on the front end. But featured image instead of displaying the selected related post images, its displaying the main post featured image to all the related posts.

```
<?PHP
$featured_posts = get_field('related_posts');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
    $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
    $title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
    $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($document->ID);
    $custom_field = get_field( 'field_name', $featured_post->ID );
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $permalink ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_html( $featured_image ); ?>" class="people-post-image"></a>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
    <span>A custom field from this post: <?php echo esc_html( $custom_field ); ?></span>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you simply have a misused variable in your code where you create the `$featured_image` variable. See my edits to your code below, along with a few other improvements.

```
    <?php
    $featured_posts = get_field('related_posts');
    if( $featured_posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
        $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
        $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($featured_post->ID);
        $custom_field = get_field( 'field_name', $featured_post->ID );
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url($permalink); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_html( $featured_image ); ?>" class="people-post-image"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
        <span>A custom field from this post: <?php echo esc_html( $custom_field ); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks vpjm3.0

I was able to work it out from your suggestion above.

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('related_posts');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
$permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
$title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
$featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $value->ID, 'full');
$custom_field = get_field( 'field_name', $featured_post->ID );
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $permalink ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_html( $featured_image ); ?>" class="people-post-image"></a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
<span>A custom field from this post: <?php echo esc_html( $custom_field ); ?></span>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```